# RXjava with MVVM and Retrofit

Tags: android, rx-java, android-mvvm

I want to use RxJava with MVVM but I don't understand why it doesn't respond CompositeDisposable with my Response class

I want to deal with RxJava that is by but I don't know how to link CompositeDisposable  with

LiveData

...

```
LiveData
     public
        LiveData <HomeResponse> setMenu() {
            final MutableLiveData <HomeResponse> data = new MutableLiveData <>( );

                compositeDisposable.add(apiRequest.getMenu()
                                                .subscribeOn( Schedulers.io())
                                                .observeOn( AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                                .subscribe( new Consumer <Response<HomeResponse>>() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void accept(Response<HomeResponse>
                                                     registrationModelResponse) throws Exception  {

                                                       data.setValue(registrationModelResponse.body());
                                                    }
                                                }));



            return data;
        }
```

.....
Response class :

```
  public
class HomeResponse {

    @SerializedName("status")
    @Expose
    private String status;
    @SerializedName("totalResults")
    @Expose
    private Integer totalResults;
    @SerializedName("Menu")
    @Expose
    private List <MainMenu> MainMenu = null;

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Integer getTotalResults() {
        return totalResults;
    }

    public void setTotalResults(Integer totalResults) {
        this.totalResults = totalResults;
    }

    public List<MainMenu> getMainMenu() {
        return MainMenu;
    }

    public void setAUsers(List<MainMenu> MainMenu) {
        this.MainMenu = MainMenu;
    }
}
```

.....
my API :

```
  @GET("getmenu.php")
   Observable<List <HomeResponse>> getMenu();
```

..............
error hear ...

```
 .subscribe( new Consumer <Response<HomeResponse>>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void accept(Response<HomeResponse>
                                                 registrationModelResponse) throws Exception  {

                                                   data.setValue(registrationModelResponse.body());
                                                }
                                            }));
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqtYw.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think's maybe you confuse how to handle `LiveData`.

Regularly, if you want to get value from `LiveData`, your activity or fragment is the one who need to observe it. Like this example.

```
// I have 'valueA' as variable in viewModel.
val valueA = MutableLiveData<String>()


// In Main Activity. I observe 'valueA' here
fun initObserver() {
    viewModel.valueA.observe(this, Observer { it -> // it is value of livedata 'data'
        // do something with 'valueA'.
    })
}
```

And your `setMenu()` function should not return value from API because when you call API like that it's asynchronous call. So when you return your value your API call still not complete.

This should be your function.

```
public void setMenu() {
        final MutableLiveData <List<HomeResponse>> data = new MutableLiveData <>( );

            compositeDisposable.add(apiRequest.getMenu()
                                            .subscribeOn( Schedulers.io())
                                            .observeOn( AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                                            .subscribe( new Consumer <List<HomeResponse>>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void accept(List<HomeResponse>
                                                 registrationModelResponse) throws Exception  {

                                                   data.setValue(registrationModelResponse);
                                                }
                                            }));



    }
```

PS. Sorry for my terrible English skill.

PS2. Your Response from API will return `List<HomeResponse>`, but in your comsumer it's become `Result<HomeResponse>` so it's will cause error.

Comment: If I change "new Consumer <Response <HomeResponse>> ()" to "new Consumer <List <HomeResponse>> ()" I cannot get
                                                     "                                                   data.setValue(registrationModelResponse.body());
;"

Comment: Please check my answer again.

Comment: If you're using java you don't need live data for that. You can archieve it with RxJava only. Then if you will be using kotlin use live data with coroutines instead.